# How to put an image side by side with a text?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4.

My question is quite simple: how to put an image side by side with a text using bootstrap ?

This is my code:

```
    <div class="card-content">
       <div class="portfolio-desc">
           <h3><a href="<?php echo $galleryLink; ?>"><?php echo $galleryTitle; ?></a></h3>
           <img id="authorImg" style="border-radius: 50%; height: 36px;" src="<?php echo $author_photo; ?>" />
           <span id=authorSpan"><?php echo $galleryAuthor; ?></span>
           <span>Gallery: <?php echo $galleryName; ?></span>
       </div>
    </div>
```

How can I put "authorImg" side by Side with authorSpan ?

Now, each img, span etc are on new line .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Images do not cause a line break by default, so it must be some additional css or other formatting. try removing some classes and see if that fixes the problem. If you find a class that causes the line break then add `whitespace: nowrap;` to that class; I tried this myself and the image was on the same line as the text so it may be some additional css you wrote.
Side note: your id does not have the first quote mark.